# jQuery send submited range slider value to a remote server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that has multiple range sliders with matching submit buttons so i can submit each slider value after the user changes it and send it to a server where a program is running a function that returns the square of this value and return it back to me. This is the code  i'm using :

```
    $(window).on("load", function(){
         var slider = $(".slider");
         slider.change(function(){
            var output= this.value;
            $(".formoid").submit(function(event) {
                posting= $.get( "http://192.168.4.49:8002/data", { n:output });
                posting.done(function(data){
                console.log(data)
                });
            });
         });
    });
```

(Html)

```
   <div id='Services' style="display:none;">
           <span class="Content_Title"> Demand <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Tertiary <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Services </span>
           <div id="svg_Services"></div>
           <div id="slider_box">
             <div class="Slider"><input type="range" class="slider" min="0" max="100" name="output10"></div> 
             <b><div class="output" id="output10">value: %</div></b>
           </div>
           <form class="formoid" title="" method="get">
                 <div>
                     <input type="submit" class="btn-info" id="submitButton"  name="submitButton" value="Submit Value">
                 </div>
           </form>  
    </div>

    <div id='Agriculture' style="display:none;">
        <span class="Content_Title"> Demand <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Tertiary <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Agriculture </span>
        <div id="svg_Agriculture"></div>
        <div id="slider_box">
          <div class="Slider"><input type="range" class="slider" min="0" max="100" name="output11"></div> 
          <b><div class="output" id="output11">value: %</div></b>
        </div>
        <form class="formoid" title="" method="get">
              <div>
                  <input type="submit" class="btn-info" id="submitButton"  name="submitButton" value="Submit Value">
              </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The problem is that each time i submit another slider's value i get the previous one as well.For example if i move the first slider to a value of 3 i get 9 in my console.If after this i move another slider to a value of 2 i get 9 and 4. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Where is the value 9 coming from? Would you have a whole code snippet we could try running to understand the problem better?

Comment: Might want to include the HTML. Also whats going on with the `.submit()`?

Comment: there is a rest API that runs with python hub to which i send the initial value ( 3 in the example) via the .get()  there the value is squared and is returned back

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want the form to submit, therefore you don't need a 'submit' handler, let alone an accumulation of 'submit' handlers that grows every time one of the sliders is changed.

Instead, attach a 'click' handler that :

- inhibits form submission
- finds the button's corresponding slider element
- executes `$.get(...)...`

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    $(".formoid").on('click', 'button', function(e) { // guess; adjust as necessary to delegate button click handling to the form. 
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent buttons submitting the form
        var $slider = $(this).prev('input'); // guess; adjust as necessary to select the appropriate slider relative to the clicked button
        $.get( "http://192.168.4.49:8002/data", { n: $slider.val() }).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Without sight of the HTML, there's a couple of guesses in there so be prepared to do some debugging.

**EDIT:**

With sight of the HTML, the javascript becomes :

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    $(".btn-info").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission.
        var $slider = $(this.form).closest('div').find("input.slider");
        $.get( "http://192.168.4.49:8002/data", { n: $slider.val() }).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks this works in a mach cleaner way but steel have the same problem i will include some html in my code above.Hope that helps.

Comment: I'll try that as well but  i actually fixed it by using on click instead of submit  in my code and by making the output var "global" so then can be used in the .get()  independently.